How does Unity get the mouse double-click file outside the program
If I have created a music player that is a singleton instance and associated with MP3 files, and I have already opened my player. Then, if I double-click an MP3 file through the system file manager (outside my player), how does my music player retrieve the path of that MP3 file?
I want to retrieve the path of the file that was double-clicked.

Double clicking always launches a new program. That new program doesn't necessarily need to show any user interface. There are a number of mechanisms by which that program can locate an already running instance, pass file details to that running instance and exit and/or choose to launch a full UI if it doesn't find a running instance. If you're already using a specific mechanism to implement a singleton instance, please identify that and hopefully it already has a specific mechanism to do the inter-process communication to pass new file details.
